# Google Cloud Platform solution for serverless log ingestion (files downloading) from a SFTP server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, sftp

There was a question today, which was deleted (don’t know why) while I typed the answer. As the answer is long, I decided **to copy/recreate it and provide my answer** anyway. Maybe it will be useful for somebody.

---

Here is the original question:

We have an SFTP server where Apache, Nginx, Wordpress logs are dumped. We want to back-up those logs into Cloud Storage and at the same time parse the contents of those logs and insert into BigQuery tables. I usually work with Cloud Functions (either NodeJS or Python) and that first comes to my mind as a go-to solution.

However, Cloud Function has a trigger, which does not make sense if my objective is for a program to continuously watch/observe/listen on the SFTP folder for new files. If my requirement is less strict, I can trigger it on schedule, say hourly to read the SFTP folder for new files. Also Cloud Functions works on the part when new files are dumped into Cloud Storage, triggering the function to do parsing of the log files and inserting to BigQuery.

If I stick with the requirement of continuously listening to SFTP folder, can you suggest a better design solution and what combination of GCP services (aside from Cloud Storage and BigQuery) I need to put together in order to accomplish this?

How about with the less strict requirement, is my solution good enough?
P.S. I just found out that the SFTP credentials have read-only privileges. So renaming the files that are done by adding suffix is out of question. Should I use a cache like MemoryStore to remember which files are done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Longread.

From my point of view this is a very big question. And solution requires not only code development, but also a significant amount of design thinking and decisions (including some compromises).

Based on my personal experience (I developed such solution twice, maintained it in production, etc) it is possible to use cloud functions together with a set of of GCP resources - secret manager, pubsub topics, firestore collections, service accounts and IAM for them and so on... Depending on your requirements (which I don't know in details) and the context - you might need to create a functional component which consists of a few (let's say between two and five) different cloud functions. Two - if your files a small (up to 100M each), the daily number of files is not big (a few thousands or tens of thousands of files), and you have rights to delete the original file from the SFTP server upon downloading.

If you don't have such rights - there should be some other process which cleans the 'old' or 'already downloaded' files. Otherwise, eventually the solution won't' work (when the downloading of just a list of files, not the files, but just a list of files, takes more than 540 seconds).

SFTP is a 'passive' component - it won't inform us if new files arrive, so there should be some 'active' component on our side to originate a connection to the SFTP server. It is a 'pull' interaction, and there is regularity - i.e. every 10, 15, or 20 minutes - connect to the SFTP server and check if there is anything new to download.

Next. Cloud Functions are idempotent, and it is not possible to store/keep the state of a file downloading just within a cloud function. There should be some external (relative to the Cloud Functions) service to maintain the state machine fo the downloading process for every file. I used a Firestore. It very convenient and has very small latency. Each document in the firestore collection represent a reflection of a 'process of a file downloading' - a state machine together with plenty of metadata, history of state transitions and so on.

Cloud Functions have 2 important restrictions:

1. 540 seconds timeout.
2. 2Gb of memory.

It means that the downloading process (and any other activities) should not exceed 540 seconds. And if you are to store any data in memory (of the cloud function) that data chunk should be smaller than 2Gb.

Can the timeout restriction affect the process? - Yes it can. The bottleneck of the whole process is the "bandwidth" between the SFTP server and the GCP point of presence. The bigger the file - the longer it will take to download it, especially when many files are being downloaded in parallel.

So, very shortly the algorithm works in the following way:

1/ The first cloud function is triggered every, let's say,  15 minutes (Cloud Scheduler => PubSub topic => cloud function). The cloud function reads configurations (i.e. json file from the GCS bucket) for all SFTP connections and all data pipelines (as this component might work with many SFTP servers, and for each SFTP server there may be many data pipelines), then gets credentials from the Secret Manager (for each SFTP server), then connects to the SFTP server, and downloads lists of available files for each connection/pipeline. Thus for every file we know - connection (SFTP server), pipeline (i.e source directory), file name, file size, file modification timestamp. I would not expect anything more from the SFTP server. For every connection and data pipeline we compose a list of (depends on configurations and that should be flexible) files up to 5, or 8 or 10 thousands of files. That list as a json structure is pushed into a PubSub topic as a message (with some additional metadata if required). So, if we have 2 SFTP servers, and 3 pipelines in each of them - there will be at least 6 messages. May be more, if a directory in the SFTP server contains more than 5K, or 8K, or 10K files. At this moment, we don't know if those files were downloaded, or the downloading process is in progress, or it has failed, or this is a new file.
When this function is deployed - the "max instances" argument has value 1.

2/ The second cloud function is triggered by a PubSub message which contain a list of files (for some SFTP server and some pipeline). For every file from the incoming list, the cloud function should make a decision what is to be done:

1. This is a new file, and it should be downloaded.
2. This is a downloading in progress and we need to wait more - do nothing.
3. This is an already downloaded file and we do nothing.
4. This is a downloading in progress, but it takes too long - probably the downloading crashed, and it should be downloaded again.
5. This is ... there may be more cases to handle...

Now the firestore collection is required. Each document in the collection - a reflection of what happens with the file; everything is recorded there - when the downloading process started, when (or if) it finished and so on. The document ID is a hash calculated based on available metadata - connection (SFTP server), pipeline (i.e source directory), source file name, source file size, source file modification timestamp. All of that comes from the message.

For example, we calculate the hash and check if such document exists in the collection. If it does not exist - create a new document, as this is a completely new file for downloading. Then compose a json message and push it into the second PubSub topic - the next cloud function is going to work on it. It it exists - it is necessary to decide what we are going to do with it - do nothing (because it is already downloaded, or because the downloading is probably still in progress) or trigger its downloading again - compose a json message and push it into the second PubSub topic...

When this function is deployed - the "max instances" argument has value between 4 and 12 (in my experience).

3/ The third cloud function is triggered by a PubSub message which contain details of a file for downloading. The following steps to be done:

1. Check that this file is not being downloaded by another cloud function
2. Update the firestore document - we start the downloading process
3. Get configuration details (from json file in GCS)
4. Get connection details (from the Secret Manager)
5. Connection and downloading
6. Save the downloaded file into the target GCS bucket
7. Update the firestore document - we finished the downloading process

When this function is deployed - the "max instances" argument has value between 10 and 30 (in my experience).

That is a very short description, under the most simple assumptions (i.e. you don't have file larger than 100Mb or/and the connection is good).

Some additional things to have in mind.

1/ Accurate logging. Json structures with the consistent fields are to be logged regularly. I would suggest to make a sink, so the log can be analysed in BigQuery tables.

2/ Service Accounts and IAM. All of that should run under a custom service account used only for the given component. Relevant IAM roles are to be provided.

3/ Cloud NAT. SFTP (in my experience) works only with specific static IP addresses (they won't allow connection from any address). Thus, a network, subnet, IP address, router, NAT - all of that is to be created and configured. The IP address is to be provided the the SFTP server owner, to allow access. Cloud functions to be deployed with "vpc connector" arguments.

4/ The progress and monitoring - 3 sources of information - firestore collection, Stackdriver logs, BigQuery tables.

Again, this is a very simplified description from the top of my mind. Let me know if you have specific questions or would like to discuss.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I deleted the original question bec for some reason that I don't know there are already 2 votes to close the question.

Comment: I can add a diagram if you would like... Let me know, please.

Comment: Yeah it's okay. I can picture your solution in my head. Much appreciated.