# Cloud Functions: create and start GCE VM, then copy startup scripts from GCS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-api-nodejs-client

We have some program that we want to write to Cloud Functions but since this is SFTP-to-GCS scheduled program (Cloud Functions only allow HTTP), it is currently not possible. So the alternative is for a scheduled Cloud Function to fire up a GCE VM and execute the SFTP-to-GCS thing, then stop it when it is done, as illustrated [here](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule). I also have some idea already how to instantiate and start (and stop) those VM using NodeJS `@google-cloud/compute` library (according to [this article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/start-stop-compute-engine-instance-from-cloud-function-bf9ae5199609)).

If I have my start-up scripts and program in GCS, how do I make Cloud Function to copy those in the instantiated VM and then prodding the VM running those programs?

Comment: Wait, why your sftp to gcs doesn't work on Cloud Functions? What's the relation with HTTP and HTTPS?

Comment: https://medium.com/google-cloud/sftp-access-to-google-cloud-storage-43ffd6134b0e

Comment: Neil's article is about a SFTP server (which uses GCS as a backend - to store the files), the article is not about a SFTP client. If you need a client - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66050709/google-cloud-platform-solution-for-serverless-log-ingestion-files-downloading

Answer (score 1):

With Compute Engine you can set a [start-up script hosted on GCS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#cloud-storage) (of course the service account of the VM need to have access to this bucket).

Then, in your start-up script, run what you want. For example, a download of the app, from GCS or Github, and then a run.

You can also define a schedule in your start up script to end the VM after X minutes, or create a Cloud Scheduler to stop it regularly. Or event create a Cloud Functions that you client call at the end of the transfert to stop/delete the VM.