# How to build a function (in Python) that calls the data from different (hubspot) API-keys in Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: python, loops, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

At our company we store all our data in Google BigQuery. Most of the data we use comes from Hubspot. We import our data into BigQuery through Cloud Functions calling the Hubspot API key. We call data from our own Hubspot account but also from the accounts of all our clients. Right now we have deployed 13 cloud functions for each seperate API-key. Since all these functions are the same (except for the API-key) it seems more logical to build one big function that loops over each API key and executes the function. However we have run into some issues trying to build this, raising also some other questions:

1. To run a cloud function you have to set a timeout time, the maximum for this is 540 seconds (9 minutes). This means that the code can take maximum 9 minutes to execute before it stops. For some of our clients alone running the function can take a few minutes, therefore if we loop over all the API-keys it will take longer than 9 minutes with the current code.
   Therefore we have to improve the efficiency of our code to make it run faster. Maybe we are using some slow methods, functions, loops? Does anybody have a tip on how to make our code faster?
2. In the current code we loop over the pages within the API. We call all rows and parameters for the objects; contacts, companies and deals. All the parameters are imported, but there are some discrepancies between the number of rows that are imported per object and the number of rows that exist in Hubspot. So far it seems that somehow the deals, contacts or companies are not imported from the final page that is called through the code. The code sets a limit of 100 rows per page (for each object) and then loops over the pages of the object until the final page and appends all these rows into one dataframe. We seem to be doing something wrong with calling the rows on the final pages.
   The solution to this problem is that we need to solve the pagination loop so it also appends the rows in in the final page. Once we solve that we can also increase the speed of the code by setting the limit higher than 100, so it has to loop over less pages. Can anybody spot the mistake we make when we loop over the pages?
3. Another solution would be to deploy the code in compute engine and store the data cloud storage. From cloud storage we could run a code that cleans the data and exports the clean data to BigQuery, so that we can work with it from there. This method would also save costs. We have only started working in the Google Cloud platform a couple of months ago, are there any experts here that have tips on how to set up our environment as efficient as possible?

A lot of background information, but I hope somebody can help! Here you can find the code that we use in Cloud Functions right now (the one that we have 13 of with different API keys):

```
    # url to query deal properties
    api_key = 'xxx'
    # query params: apikey
    querystring = {"hapikey": api_key}
    headers = {'accept': 'application/json'}

    #### Deal Properties
    url = "https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/deal/properties/"
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    dealproperties = response.json()


    #### Company Properties
    url = "https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/company/properties/"
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    companyproperties = response.json()


    #### Contact properties
    url = "https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/contacts/properties/"
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    contactproperties = response.json()


    ### Deal data
    url = "https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/deals/"
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    querystring = {
        'hapikey': api_key,
        'limit': '100',
        'properties': dealproperties,
        'associations': ['companies', 'contacts']

    }

    response = requests.request('GET', url, headers=headers, params=querystring).json()
    data = response

    if 'paging' in response:
        after = data['paging']['next']['after']
        querystring['after'] = after

    deals = []
    page=0
    # iteration through each page
    while after:
        # iteration through each deal in a page
        for i in range(len(data['results'])):
            if 'associations' in data['results'][i]:
                if 'companies' in data['results'][i]['associations']:
                    companies_info = data['results'][i][
                        'associations'
                    ]['companies']['results']
                    companies_id = [
                        companies_info[i]['id'] for i in range(len(companies_info))
                    ]
                    data['results'][i]['properties']['associated_companies_id'] = companies_id

                if 'contacts' in data['results'][i]['associations']:
                    contacts_info = data['results'][i][
                        'associations'
                    ]['contacts']['results']
                    contacts_id = [
                        contacts_info[i]['id'] for i in range(len(contacts_info))
                    ]
                    data['results'][i]['properties']['associated_contacts_id'] = contacts_id
            deals.append(data['results'][i]['properties'])

        # new query for next page
        print('page ', page, 'processed')
        page += 1
        response = requests.request('GET', url, headers=headers, params=querystring).json()
        data = response
        if 'paging' in data:
            after = data['paging']['next']['after']
            querystring['after'] = after
        else:
            break


    df_deals = pd.DataFrame(deals)
    df_deals['Company'] = 'Example_client'
    #Add deal owners
    querystring = {"hapikey": api_key}
    headers = {'accept': 'application/json'}

    #### Owners
    url = "https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/owners"
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    owners= response.json()

    #Df from dict
    owners = pd.DataFrame(owners['results'])

    #Merge fname and lname
    owners['FullNameDealOwner'] = owners['firstName'] + ' ' + owners['lastName']

    #Keep id and fullname
    idowners = owners[['id', 'FullNameDealOwner']]

    #Rename id to mergable column name
    idowners.rename(columns = {"id": "hubspot_owner_id"}, inplace=True)

    df_deals = pd.merge(df_deals, idowners, on="hubspot_owner_id", how='left')
    df_deals.to_csv("deals.csv")

    client = bigquery.Client(project = "our_company_project")
    dataset_ref = client.dataset("example_client_Deals")
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table("example_client_deals")
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
    job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1
    job_config.autodetect = True
    job_config.write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE"
    job_config.allow_quoted_newlines = True

    with open("deals.csv", "rb") as source_file:
        job = client.load_table_from_file(
            source_file,
            table_ref,
            location="EU",
            job_config=job_config)

    job.result()


    #### Company Data

    # url to query company properties
    url = "https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/company/properties/"
    # query params: apikey
    querystring = {"hapikey": api_key}

    headers = {'accept': 'application/json'}

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring).json()
    companyproperties = response


    #### Load properties into API call
    querystring = {
        'hapikey': api_key,
        'limit': '100',
        'properties': companyproperties
    }
    url = "https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/companies/"
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    response = requests.request('GET', url, headers=headers, params=querystring).json()
    data = response

    if 'paging' in response:
        after = data['paging']['next']['after']
        querystring['after'] = after

    companies = []
    page=0

    while after:
      # iteration through each company in a page
      for i in data['results']:
          companies.append(i['properties'])
      # new query for next page
      print('page ', page, 'processed')
      page += 1
      response = requests.request('GET', url, headers=headers, params=querystring).json()
      data = response
      if 'paging' in data:
          after = data['paging']['next']['after']
          querystring['after'] = after
      else:
          break

    df_companies = pd.DataFrame(companies)
    df_companies['Company'] = 'example_client'
    df_companies.to_csv("companies.csv")
    client = bigquery.Client(project = "our_company_project")

    dataset_ref = client.dataset("example_client_Companies")
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table("example_client_companies")
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
    job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1
    job_config.autodetect = True
    job_config.write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE"
    job_config.allow_quoted_newlines = True
    with open("companies.csv", "rb") as source_file:
        job = client.load_table_from_file(
            source_file,
            table_ref,
            location="EU",
            job_config=job_config)

    job.result()

### Contact
### Load Contact Properties in
    querystring = {
        'hapikey': api_key,
        'limit': '100',
        'properties': contactproperties,
        'associations': 'companies'}

    url = "https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/contacts/"
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    response = requests.request(
    'GET', url, headers=headers, params=querystring).json()
    data = response

    if 'paging' in response:
        after = data['paging']['next']['after']
        querystring['after'] = after

    contacts = []
    page=0
    # iteration through each page
    while after:
        # iteration through each deal in a page
        for i in range(len(data['results'])):
            if 'associations' in data['results'][i]:
                if 'companies' in data['results'][i]['associations']:
                    companies_info = data['results'][i][
                        'associations'
                    ]['companies']['results']
                    companies_id = [
                        companies_info[i]['id'] for i in range(len(companies_info))
                    ]
                    data['results'][i]['properties']['associated_companies_id'] = companies_id
            contacts.append(data['results'][i]['properties'])

        # new query for next page
        print('page ', page, 'processed')
        page += 1
        response = requests.request(
            'GET', url, headers=headers, params=querystring
        )
        data = response.json()
        if 'paging' in data:
            after = data['paging']['next']['after']
            querystring['after'] = after
        else:
            break


    df_contacts = pd.DataFrame(contacts)
    df_contacts['NowCompany'] = 'example_client'
    df_contacts.to_csv("contacts.csv")
    client = bigquery.Client(project = "our_company_project")

    dataset_ref = client.dataset("example_client_Contacts")
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table("example_client_contacts")
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
    job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1
    job_config.autodetect = True
    job_config.write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE"
    job_config.allow_quoted_newlines = True
    with open("contacts.csv", "rb") as source_file:
        job = client.load_table_from_file(
            source_file,
            table_ref,
            location="EU",
            job_config=job_config)

    job.result()
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution which you are using currently isn’t scalable. At some point, you might reach a point where the dataset is too big and the API call to Hubspot takes more than 9 minutes to complete. I think the optimal solution here would be App Engine as it’s somewhere in the middle. You can have your application there which will run only when you want as it’s serverless and scalable but at the same time, it doesn’t have the timeout constraints of a Cloud Function but it’s durable while the request is in progress.

Answer (score 0):

I won't be able to answer all questions, and I've never worked with 'Hubspot'... Anyway...

Suppose API keys and other credentitals are kept in a Secer Manager. In that case, the name of the secret received on the cloud function invocation (i.e. from a cloud scheduler through a pub sub topic) can be used as secret names  to retrive the relevant API key and implement some specialisation (if required) ... Thus, there is only one cloud function, but depending on incoming arguments - it can do different things...

I cannot comment the loop issue, as I don't know how that API works, but you might find the following question a bit interesting, as it discusses performance issues together with cloud functions timeout limitations:

[Google Cloud Platform solution for serverless log ingestion (files downloading) from a SFTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66050709/google-cloud-platform-solution-for-serverless-log-ingestion-files-downloading)

In addition, I thought there was a method to upload pandas dataframe directly to a BigQuery table, thus I am not sure if csv file in the local memory is required. Alternatively , if you don't want to fetch data from the external API again in case of any BigQuery loading issues - it may be interesting to store the file as a GCS object in some bucket, and load data into BigQuery from that object.