# Python code to transfer file from GCS to SFTP server using GCP's Cloud Function

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Hi I am newto Python and I was wondering whether someone can help me with the following:

I need to write a code in the cloud function to copy a .csv file from a bucket in GCS to a sftp server.

My bucket is called 001b and the file is called test.csv and i have the hostname user name and port number and password of the sftp server.username=uid password=mypassword port = 22 host https://....

I am trying to create a cloud function with a trigger that every time the file is created in the above bucket it will then transfer it to the sftp server. There will always be one file in the bucket as the csv is overwritten daily.

I am using 2nd gen environment and have my trigger set to Cloud Storage with event type as google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized.

I really need help with the code for main.py and requirements.txt for python 3.8

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I am not sure it is a straightforward case. Some questions to think about - (1) How the secrets are to be stored/managed? (2) What happens if the transfer (to the SFTP server) is not successful? How the user is informed, and how to sort it out? (3) The extenral SFTP server might be configured to accept incoming connections only from specific IP address, so who and how configures the required resources (subnet, static ip address, router, cloud nat, etc) in the GCP, where the cloud fucntion under discusion is deployed? () there are plenty of other questions as well to think about

Comment: Some time ago I wrote a SO answer on a question how to develop a cloud function based serverless component to download files from a SFTP server. So the information flow is in the opposite direction. It does not answer your question, but provides some hints. Here is that answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66050709/google-cloud-platform-solution-for-serverless-log-ingestion-files-downloading/66050710#66050710 I implemented that twice for different clients. One time in python, and the second time in Go (much better). I also implemented your case once (from SFTP to GCS). Similar complexity

Comment: As the code belongs to those clients, I cannot share. Sorry for that. And it is quite a lot.