# Consume from stream to Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, virtual-machine, streaming

We use Airship (push notifications and in-app messages) and there is this [Real-time Data Streaming API](https://docs.airship.com/api/connect/) they have that exposes a stream of events describing a user’s experience within a mobile app and I need to connect to it via GET request to read and to then load events to BigQuery warehouse. What would be the best and not expensive way to achieve this? I do not have much experience, so I apologise in advance if my questions/solutions are not correct. What i thought of is:

- to connect to steam from a VM and then read the events and load them to BQ using `insert_rows_json` method. Cost: running VM + BigQuery data ingestion.
- to connect to steam from a VM, create a PubSub topic with schema attached per endpoint and then publish events to PubSub topics, from where they are loaded to BQ via BQ subscription. Cost: running VM + PubSub Throughput. There are no charges for BigQuery data ingestion using BigQuery subscriptions. Later on, I could also have other subscriptions to these topics that, for ex, trigger Cloud Function to perform some action. This method is faster (i think?) because here the msgs will be protobuf encoded.

Is it even correct solution to connect to a stream from VM? Maybe this should in k8s? Or some way?  We use Cloud Composer which managed k8s cluster that we use for orchestrations. Maybe it makes sense to deploy this there?

Thank you in advance for all the suggestions!

Comment: There might be a lot of options and a choice probably depends on budget (OPEX, CAPEX), time for development/delivery of the solution, available skills, distribution of events over time, number of events per time at peak and so on. If the rate of events is significant, I might think about Apache Beam (Dataflow) to stream events into a PubSub topic and then use a BigQuery subscription. If the distribution of events is odd, and the number of events is not so big - I would think about a bespoke solution based on cloud function (plus other resources) to stream events into PubSub topic...

Comment: @al-dann thank you for your answer and recommendations! The distribution is closer to odd than significant. Wouldnt streaming from VM be cheaper than Cloud Function?

Comment: In terms of the OPEX cloud functions might be cheaper. Probably a few times cheaper than a compute engine. Especially if the later have to do nothing the majority of the time. But the design and the development might be more complex.

Comment: I can type from a proper keyboard now... Based on your description, it is necessary to make pull `GET` requests from time to time to get new chunk of messages... So, while somebody calls that a 'real time data streaming API', I have a different classification for such style. And that might be similar to any conventional REST API, or even fetching data from some SFTP server. A few years ago I answered a similar question (but it was about getting data from a SFTP server, rather than from an API). I guess, the difference is not so big (in comparison to your case), and you may find it useful. TBC

Comment: Here is the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66050709/google-cloud-platform-solution-for-serverless-log-ingestion-files-downloading/66050710#66050710 Let me know if you need more details or discussion, as I have some spare time this days.

Comment: BTW, I don't know how critical is that in your case - but in my opinion serverless solutions are much more secure than any other solution where VMs are to be used. That might be of less importance in your case, or may be very critical.

Comment: @al-dann thanks for the link, indeed its a similar case. Btw, I just measure approx throughput, its around 1k of events per minute. I read you old post and I would like to try to use this approach where i connect every 5-10 minutes to pull events that arrive after the last sync and load them to BQ. This would be near real time streaming though, right? 
Many thanks for your help again!