Monitoring File Upload in GCS
I need some help in implementing the below.

I upload a series of huge files(~2-5GB) to the GCS through an sftp gateway interface like FileZilla or by direct upload.
When the file upload is triggered in the GCS or GCS gets aware of a file being uploaded, the file name is saved in a variable like files_in_progress.
Once the file upload is done, the file name is stored in a different variable like files_uploaded
If the file is being deleted, the file name should be deleted from these 2 variables.
The contents of these two variables are compared every 5 min.
If the file names in these two variables match then a function called process_files is called.

From my understanding, I see I could use services like Cloud functions, Firestore and Pub/Sub for this but I can't come up with an entire workflow on how these services should be configured. Also, from GCS perspective (if I'm not wrong) it is either a file exists or not and this questions the feasibility of the approach. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

a discussion about a possible implementation - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66050709/google-cloud-platform-solution-for-serverless-log-ingestion-files-downloading/66050710#66050710 - might be useful to check for ideas, hints and possible traps

Do you want to keep cacheon the previously ingested files?

@guillaumeblaquiere no, I don't intend to since every ingestion will be a fresh one.

Do you need a UI wrapper around the Firestore database to expose the ongoing process (for each file)? Or you need the 'backend' solution only? Or both (can you separate those 2 things in this case)?

I need only the backend solution

OK. I think an idea of the design was outlined in the link I provided above... You mentioned a few Gb files. It might be OK if the connection between the data source (SFTP server) and GCP is good, as the cloud functions have only 540 seconds timeout (unless the design is changed). The next question is about OPEX/CAPEX/budget/time. I implemented such solution twice - the first time in Python, the second in Go (works much better). But it takes time/money to do things properly (weeks), and then to support in production. Does you company have time and money? Or third party solution is better?

Yes, I believe. And, I like to know both the In-house and the third party solution. Also, sometimes a file can go up to 80 GB in size but its rare, 1 in 20-30 files.

The size of the file influences how long does it take to download it. If you would like to use cloud functions - the timeout is from 9 minutes to 60 minutes depending on implementation... will it be enough to move the data from the SFTP server?

Alternative approaches - to use Cloud Composer (might be more - in my experience up to 10 times more  - operationally expensive than the cloud functions based solution, but more simple in support), or use external service providers like fivetran or stitch or dataddo or alooma... - they have their own benefits and drawbacks

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
